# TensorFlow: How to combine rows of tensor with summing the 2nd element of tensor which has the same 1st element?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

For example, I want to `add` the 2nd element of this tensor where the 1st element is same. Any Numpy based solution is also welcomed!

- From :

```py
x = tf.constant([
    [1., 0.9],
    [2., 0.7],
    [1., 0.7],
    [3., 0.4],
    [4., 0.8]
], dtype=tf.float32)
```

- To:

```py
x = tf.constant([
    [1., 1.6],
    [2., 0.7],
    [3., 0.4],
    [4., 0.8]
], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [FinleyGibson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10111013/finleygibson) for the Numpy solution and some useful TensorFlow pointers! This is my solution in TF with using `tf.unique_with_counts()` and `tf.segment_sum()`:

```py
x = tf.constant([
    [1., 0.9],
    [2., 0.7],
    [1., 0.7],
    [3., 0.4],
    [4., 0.8]
], dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    y, idx, y_counts = tf.unique_with_counts(x[:, 0])
    idx_sorted = tf.sort(idx, axis=-1, direction='ASCENDING')
    score_sum = tf.segment_sum(x[:, 1], idx_sorted)
    result = tf.stack((y, score_sum), axis=1)
    print(sess.run(result))

[[1.       1.5999999]
[2.        0.7      ]
[3.        0.4      ]
[4.        0.8      ]]
```

**EDIT:**

- Seems like the above solution was not properly ordering rows/columns pairs. Here is the fixed version.

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.constant([
        [2., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [3., 0.4],
        [4., 0.8],
        [1., 0.9]], dtype=tf.float32)

    def matrix_sort(a, col):
        return tf.gather(a, tf.nn.top_k(-a[:, col], k=a.get_shape()[0].value).indices)

    sorted_x = matrix_sort(matrix_sort(x, 1), 0)
    labels = sorted_x[:, 0]
    scores = sorted_x[:, 1]
    y, idx, y_counts = tf.unique_with_counts(labels)
    score_sum = tf.segment_sum(scores, idx)    
    result = tf.stack((y, score_sum), axis=1) 
    print(sess.run(result))

[[1.  1. ]
 [2.  0.7]
 [3.  0.4]
 [4.  0.8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

numpy solution:

```
x = np.array([
    [1., 0.9],
    [2., 0.7],
    [1., 0.7],
    [3., 0.4],
    [4., 0.8]])

ans = np.array([[i,np.sum(x[np.where(x[:,0]==i), 1])] for i in set(x[:,0])])
```

gives

```
array([[1. , 1.6],
       [2. , 0.7],
       [3. , 0.4],
       [4. , 0.8]])
```

you will not be able to do this for a 'tf.constant()', as it is a *constant* variable and does not support having its values changed. If you want to change values within tensorflow data structures it is best to either pass values to a [tf.placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) or use a [tf.Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable). However these require predefined dimensions, and cannot have their sizes changed as desired in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the numpy based solution but it turned out, you can do this with tf.unique_with_counts() and tf.segment_sum(). You can check my answer below.