# How to combine tensor elements with similar values of specific column?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

We got this 3D `input_tensor` which is a tensor representing `(batch_size, N, 2)`.

- Where,

  - `batch_size = total batches`
  - `N = total predictions`,
  - `2 = (label, score)`

I want to add the score values (2nd column elements) where labels (1st column elements) are same per batch. For example, given this tensor with 3 batches, 4 predictions per batch and 2 elements; I want `required_output_tensor` as result.

**Condition:** No `for loops` or `tf.map_fn()` for this answer. Reason, tf.map_fn() is SLOW on GPU with TF2.X. [You can take a look at my sample code here that is working on 2d tensor and I can use the same with tf.map_fn().](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959305/tensorflow-how-to-combine-rows-of-tensor-with-summing-the-2nd-element-of-tensor)

```py
input_tensor = tf.constant([
    [
        [2., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [3., 0.4],
        [2., 0.8],
    ],
    [
        [2., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [1., 0.4],
        [4., 0.8],
    ],
    [
        [3., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [3., 0.4],
        [4., 0.8],
    ]
])

required_output_tensor = [
    [
        [2., 1.5],
        [1., 0.1],
        [3., 0.4],
    ],
    [
        [2., 0.7],
        [1., 0.5],
        [4., 0.8],
    ],
    [
        [3., 1.1],
        [1., 0.1],
        [4., 0.8],
    ]
]
```

**EDIT:** I can see how we will end up with ragged tensor. In that case, I'm fine with choosing top-k elements per batch where k=min(size(smallest_batch)), or it can be hard coded to topk=2.

**EDIT 2:** Adding additional input to try out the proposed solution:

```py
additional_input_tensor = tf.constant([
    [
        [2., 0.5],
        [1., 0.1],
        [3., 0.4],
        [2., 0.5],
    ],
    [
        [22., 0.7],
        [11., 0.2],
        [11., 0.3],
        [44., 0.8],
    ],
    [
        [3333., 0.7],
        [1111., 0.1],
        [4444., 0.4],
        [5555., 0.8],
    ],
    [
        [2., 0.9],
        [1., 0.2],
        [5., 0.3],
        [2., 0.9],
    ]
])
```

Comment: This problem is not well defined in general, unless you used ragged tensors, since you can have a different number of repeated values on each group, which would lead to a different number of aggregated results on each group. One possible solution would be to have all labels on all groups, and fill with zeros the scores of missing labels.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, I can see that. I forgot to include that case where we ended up with ragged tensor. In that case, I'm fine with choosing say `topk` elements per batch. I've added clarification comments to original question. Thanks!

Comment: @Snehal how many classes do you have? (4?)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani: Total classes are arbitrary unfortunately. Would it help if I give you a solid number? If you have a solution then you can use `total_classes=50` in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not well defined in general, as it can happen that you have a different number of non-repeated id values in the input groups, so the result would not be a dense tensor. You could try using a ragged tensor, although that can be limiting. One option is to make a result where every group in the output has every id, and the scores for those ids that are not in the corresponding input group are simply set to zero. This is how you could do that:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_tensor = tf.constant([
    [
        [2., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [3., 0.4],
        [2., 0.8],
    ],
    [
        [2., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [1., 0.4],
        [4., 0.8],
    ],
    [
        [3., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [3., 0.4],
        [4., 0.8],
    ]
])
# Take input tensor shape
s = tf.shape(input_tensor)
# Flatten first dimensions
flat = tf.reshape(input_tensor, (-1, 2))
# Find unique id values
group_ids, group_idx = tf.unique(flat[:, 0], out_idx=s.dtype)
# Shift id indices per group in the input
num_groups = tf.reduce_max(group_idx) + 1
group_shift = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(num_groups * tf.range(s[0]), 1), (1, s[1]))
group_idx_shift = group_idx + tf.reshape(group_shift, (-1,))
# Aggregate per group in the input
num_groups_shift = num_groups * s[0]
# Either use unsorted_segment_sum
group_sum = tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(flat[:, 1], group_idx_shift, num_groups_shift)
# Or use bincount
group_sum = tf.math.bincount(group_idx_shift, weights=flat[:, 1],
                             minlength=num_groups_shift)
# Reshape and concatenate
group_sum_res = tf.reshape(group_sum, (s[0], num_groups))
group_ids_res = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(group_ids, 0), (s[0], 1))
result = tf.stack([group_ids_res, group_sum_res], axis=-1)
# Sort results
result_s = tf.argsort(group_sum_res, axis=-1, direction='DESCENDING')
result_sorted = tf.gather_nd(result, tf.expand_dims(result_s, axis=-1), batch_dims=1)
print(result_sorted.numpy())
# [[[2.  1.5]
#   [3.  0.4]
#   [1.  0.1]
#   [4.  0. ]]
# 
#  [[4.  0.8]
#   [2.  0.7]
#   [1.  0.5]
#   [3.  0. ]]
# 
#  [[3.  1.1]
#   [4.  0.8]
#   [1.  0.1]
#   [2.  0. ]]]
```

EDIT:

Here is an alternative using a ragged tensor output instead:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_tensor = tf.constant([...])
# Same as before
s = tf.shape(input_tensor)
flat = tf.reshape(input_tensor, (-1, 2))
group_ids, group_idx = tf.unique(flat[:, 0], out_idx=s.dtype)
num_groups = tf.reduce_max(group_idx) + 1
group_shift = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(num_groups * tf.range(s[0]), 1), (1, s[1]))
group_idx_shift = group_idx + tf.reshape(group_shift, (-1,))
# Apply unique again to find ids per batch
group_ids2_ref, group_idx2 = tf.unique(group_idx_shift)
group_ids2 = tf.gather(group_ids, group_ids2_ref % num_groups)
# Also can use unsorted_segment_sum here if preferred
group_sum = tf.math.bincount(group_idx2, weights=flat[:, 1])
# Count number of elements in each output group
out_sizes = tf.math.bincount(group_ids2_ref // num_groups, minlength=s[0])
# Make ragged result
group_sum_r = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(group_sum, out_sizes)
group_ids_r = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(group_ids2, out_sizes)
result = tf.stack([group_ids_r, group_sum_r], axis=-1)
print(*result.to_list(), sep='\n')
# [[2.0, 1.5], [1.0, 0.10000000149011612], [3.0, 0.4000000059604645]]
# [[2.0, 0.699999988079071], [1.0, 0.5], [4.0, 0.800000011920929]]
# [[3.0, 1.100000023841858], [1.0, 0.10000000149011612], [4.0, 0.800000011920929]]
```

Comment: Pretty solid solution! Just one question, is there any difference between using `unsorted_segment_sum ` or `bincount` latency wise or anything? I'll test and accept this answer & reward the bounty points in 6 hours unless anyone else come up with something else or I find any corner cases. In anyway, this is a very good solution. 

Comment: @Snehal I put both alternatives because I'm not sure if there is any significant difference between the two, it might depend on both the shape of the array and the number of classes I guess. There is no rush in awarding the bounty, you can keep it up for the days you have remaining to attract other potential answers.

Comment: @Snehal I added an alternative implementation producing a ragged tensor as a result, which could be useful if you have a large number of different ids in total but just a few in each batch.

Comment: It seems like your two proposed solutions are not ranking the 1st columns with respect to 2nd column. I've added a bigger `input_tensor` to test out both of the above solutions. For the simplicity, I'm also attaching this gist with everything discussed here. It shows top-3 results per batch, I'm sorting the final `result` by 2nd column returning top-3 elements per batch. https://gist.github.com/spate141/4ea446a7cf0d501811ed6cc20b214226

Comment: @Snehal Ah, I wasn't aware that was a requirement. I changed the dense solution to have a sorted result. For the ragged tensor, I'm not sure how that could be done effectively, since there is not `tf.argsort` for ragged tensors and there is no TensorFlow equivalent of `np.lexsort` that could help here either...

Comment: I think by flattening the 1st dimension with `flat = tf.reshape(input_tensor, (-1, 2))` will loose the crucial information of each batch being treated separately. That will lead to wrong final result. I can see why it is necessary to flatten the tensor because of the `tf.unique` not supporting 2D tensor. (Note: You can check this https://rb.gy/iwurqa for `unique_with_counts_v2`). For testing out, I'm adding another input that you can try, you can see there how it fails in producing proper final tensor.

Comment: @Snehal Sorry, I see I did something wrong with the initial sorting, which is actually not necessary since you want the results sorted by score anyway. I've tested it with the new input example you have given and I think it is correct now.

Comment: SPOT ON! Now it's perfect, it passed all test cases that I throw at it! Only If I could give you more than 50 bounty points! For you my sir: https://rb.gy/fdgjsh

Comment: It looks like I got stuck at one similar problem with some twist. Do you mind taking a look at this? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177159/how-to-select-top-n-elements-from-the-tensor-by-the-most-popular-element-of-spec

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely as you asked, but if you know the number of classes, and you don't want to have a ragged tensor, you can use one-hot encodings to add the different scores for the same classes:

```
input_tensor = tf.constant([
    [
        [2., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [3., 0.4],
        [2., 0.8],
    ],
    [
        [2., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [1., 0.4],
        [4., 0.8],
    ],
    [
        [3., 0.7],
        [1., 0.1],
        [3., 0.4],
        [4., 0.8],
    ]
])


number_of_classes = 5

#first split the labels from scores
labels = tf.expand_dims(input_tensor[:,:,0], axis=-1)
scores = tf.expand_dims(input_tensor[:,:,1], axis=-1)

#get a one-hot encoding for the labels
#the way you do this would likely depend on your specific labels
#the way I do it here is not very robust (maybe use half open intervals instead)
class_indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(number_of_classes, dtype=tf.float32), shape=(1,1,number_of_classes))
one_hots = tf.cast(tf.equal(class_indices, labels), tf.float32)
print(one_hots.shape)  # (batch, N, number_of_classes)

#now multiply the one hots by the scores, and add all together
scored_one_hots = scores * one_hots
scores_per_index = tf.reduce_sum(scored_one_hots, axis=1) # (batch, number_of_classes) 
# where the second index denotes the class and contains the score for that class

# now finish up by combining these scores with the labels
# edit: of course this part too depends on how you actually did the encoding
batch_size = input_tensor.shape[0]
ordered_labels = tf.repeat(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(number_of_classes, dtype=tf.float32), axis=0), batch_size, axis=0)

result = tf.stack([ordered_labels, scores_per_index], axis=2)
print(result)
```

print result:

```
(3, 4, 5)
tf.Tensor(
[[[0.  0. ]
  [1.  0.1]
  [2.  1.5]
  [3.  0.4]
  [4.  0. ]]

 [[0.  0. ]
  [1.  0.5]
  [2.  0.7]
  [3.  0. ]
  [4.  0.8]]

 [[0.  0. ]
  [1.  0.1]
  [2.  0. ]
  [3.  1.1]
  [4.  0.8]]], shape=(3, 5, 2), dtype=float32)
```

The way you make your one-hots would depend on the specifics of the labels (tf.equals might not be the best choice, but you can use comparisons etc.).

Comment: While this is an acceptable solution where you know the encoding of the labels or how the range; it will not scale well for say 500K labels or when there is no specific order in labels. Thanks for the answer anyway. This was a good take on the question.